# Problem finding string atached to json file when translating (i18n)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, i18next

I have successfully translated many of the pages on my website project but now I have moved to translate specific components that were created and it is not working.

The error message I get is as follows: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'titulo')"

**Note: I am using NextJS and TailwindCSS

This is the code for the JSON file strings where it should grab the translation, I have two files, one for ES (Spanish) and another EN (English)

```
"heroBanner":{
        "titulo": "Ayudamos a PYMES a Captar la Atención mediante Publicidad Digital",
        "subtitulo": "BIENVENIDO A COTTONMEDIA"
    },
```

This is the component code where I have passed the props:

```
import React from 'react'
import Custom__Cursor from './Custom__Cursor'

function Hero__Banner(props) {
  
  return (
    <div>

      <div className="relative h-screen">

        <div className="h-full w-full">
          <video autoPlay muted loop className="object-cover h-screen w-full ">
            <source src="/AdsBgVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </source>
          </video>
        </div>

        <div className="absolute top-0 h-full w-full bg-black opacity-60 z-10"></div>

        <div className="absolute top-1/4 z-20 max-w-screen-md md:max-w-screen-xl">
          <div className='flex flex-col px-10 space-y-5'>
            <p className='text-left text-sm md:text-base font-medium tracking-wide filter drop-shadow-md'>{props.titulo}</p>
            <p className='text-left text-4xl md:text-5xl leading-normal md:leading-relaxed filter drop-shadow-md'>{props.subtitulo}</p>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Hero__Banner
```

Then where the component is rendered I have included these props with the string in order to get the translation as follows:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Hero__Banner from '../components/Hero__Banner'
import ScrollToTop from '../components/ScrollToTop'

export default function Home(props) {

  const { index, heroBanner } = props;


  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/short-logo.svg" />
      </Head>

      
      {/*Main content */}

      {/* Hero section */}

      <Hero__Banner 
        titulo={heroBanner.titulo}
        subtitulo={heroBanner.subtitulo}
      />

    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps({locale}) {
  const response = await import(`../lang/${locale}.json`);

  return {
    props: {
      index: response.default.index,
      heroBanner: response.default.heroBanner
    },
  };
}
```

Even after doing that, I still get the same error, not sure why this is happening. The component translations are now on the index page which is in "pages", so it should work in my opinion. As you can see in the code, I already have some translated sections in the index, which work perfectly.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhq0I.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible heroBanner is not translated for all languages? You may check if it is not undefined, before accessing its properties

Comment: @adrai I have tried accessing heroBanner without specifying its properties and seems to work correctly (i get no error, just a blank space where the string should be).

Comment: What is the output of response.default ?

Comment: @adrai the output of reponse.default is still set to heroBanner, not sure if that is what you are asking. I used somebody else's code for the translation and that's how they said it should be used

Comment: `getStaticProps` only works on page components, i.e. components under the `pages` folder that are used as routes in your app. Is `Hero__Banner` a page component?

Comment: @juliomalves I believe the problem has to do with that, it's the only difference between some of the pages I'm translating. Hero__Banner is in a separate folder called "components" not in the pages folder. And I hard-coded those strings instead of adding props to the component, if I did so, would that fix the issue, or do I have to change something else? Thanks

Comment: Of course hardcoding values would work, but you can still use `getStaticProps` in the page component that renders the `Hero__Banner` component, and pass the translations down to it.

Comment: @juliomalves Could you check the post again, I have added an EDIT section where I have tried to implement your answer but for some reason still get the same error.

Comment: Does `response.default.heroBanner` have the expect value inside `getStaticProps`?

Comment: @juliomalves I’m new to React and therefore not quite sure where to look in order to answer your question

Comment: If you log `response.default.heroBanner` to the console inside `getStaticProps`, what do you get?

Comment: @juliomalves Seems like it was an error with the localhost, everytime I change the language on a new page I have to restart the localhost otherwise I get that. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are translating with i18n, and get this error, it could be because you have altered the translation JSON file and the server needs to be restarted. That was the case for me, hope this helps.